# How to change the IMAGE of table data with javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have this problem where i define a table(may not be the most effective way of doing it but that is not the problem) which works out just fine for me. However, when I try to change the contents of tabledata assigned with its ID, nothing happnes, no new image is displayed instead of the one that has been assigned to id at the creation of the table.

```
var idArray = window.idArray;
var imgArray = window.imgArray;
var prArray = window.prArray;

var screenH = screen.height/2.1;
var screenW = screen.width/2.1;

var tdW;
var tdH;

function createTables(){

    if(idArray.length>2){
        rows=2;
        cols=2;
        tdW='100%';
        tdH='100%';
    }else if(idArray.length==2){
        rows=1;
        cols=2;
        tdW='100%';
        tdH='100%';
    }else if(idArray.length==1){
        tdW='100%';
        tdH='100%';
    }

    var table = '';
    for(var r=0;r<rows;r++){
        table += '<tr>';
        for(var c=0;c<cols;c++){
            table += '<td style="max-width:'+tdW+';max-height:'+tdH+';" id="c'+r+''+c+'">';
            table += '<img style="max-height:'+screenH+';max-width:'+screenW+';" src="'+imgArray[2]+'"';
            table += '</td>';
        }
        table += '</tr>';
    }
    document.write("<table>"+table+"</table>");
}

function addImage(r,c){
    document.getElementById('c'+r+''+c).innerHTML('<img style="max-height:'+screenH+';max-width:'+screenW+';" src="'+imgArray[1]+'"');
}
```

everything works fine untill I try to change the image in particular column of the particular row so it would begin displaying instead of the first picture assigned to the cell with its' id. id of the cell: ***'c00'*** (the problem is the function addImage().. this "innerHTML" stuff doesnt work for me..).

I really don't get it...

Thats the main php file:

```
    <?php
    include "includes/connect.php";
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="includes/style.css">
        <title>Cablex-T OG</title>
    </head>
        <?php
            $idArray = array();
            $imgArray = array();
            $prArray = array();
            fillArrays();
        ?>
        <script>
            var idArray = <?php echo json_encode($idArray) ?>;
            var imgArray = <?php echo json_encode($imgArray) ?>;
            var prArray = <?php echo json_encode($prArray) ?>;
        </script>
        <script src="includes/script.js"></script>
    <body>

        <script>
        createTables();
        addImage(1,2);

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Assign unique `ID` to `<tr>` then try like `ID->td->img`

Comment: Im afraid i don't understand your suggestion

Comment: @ZaidBinKhalid AFAIK the id is unique - see the two loops.

Comment: `everything works fine until...` - what does happen? Can you describe what the error is and what you expect?

Comment: yes the ids are c00 c01 c11 and 12.. i know they are unique

Comment: @gus27 wait 5 sec.. i think its pretty clear tho...

Comment: Currently, you are trying to access `<td>` by id that is under `<tr>` so I suggest you need to pass the unique id to `<tr>` then access `<td>` with parent reference and change image.

Comment: @ZaidBinKhalid Please post your complete answer so I can full understand what you are saying :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function addImage(){
    document.getElementById('c'+r+''+c).innerHTML('<img style="max-height:'+screenH+';max-width:'+screenW+';" src="'+imgArray[1]+'"');
```

}

Tis function depends on values of `r` and `c` but those values don't seem to be passed to the function.

Do you maybe want to define it with:
    function addImage(someR, and Some c){
       //...
     }

and then call:

```
addImage(1, 2)
```

Comment: Ofcourse... i feel so stupid :P.. it still doesn't work tho.. the screen is now just point blank white

Comment: You are calling `addImage()` from your main php file. How are you getting the values for the function? Maybe you want to call that function from within your for look where you have those values? But then, it looks like you are already setting a `src` url in the loop.

Comment: i download the files from database.. i am just passing it manually right now this is work in progress. yes i assing all 4 places with an image at the start please read the full question..

Comment: One other thing `innerHTML` is not a function. Try setting it with `innerHTML = `